# Google analytics embedded API not working with Google Analytics Reporting API (v4)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-api, google-analytics-api

I want to show google analytics data to my client site and in some reason gapi won't recognize reporting api v4. Can someone help me with this?

Home.components.ts

```js
  constructor(
    private credentialService: CredentialsService,
    private router: Router,
    public gapiService: GoogleApiService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gapiService.onLoad().subscribe( () => {
      const VIEW_ID = '216494010';

      function queryReports() {
        gapi.client.request({
          path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
          root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
          method: 'POST',
          body: {
            reportRequests: [
              {
                viewId: VIEW_ID,
                dateRanges: [
                  {
                    startDate: '7daysAgo',
                    endDate: 'today'
                  }
                ],
                metrics: [
                  {
                    expression: 'ga:sessions'
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
      }

      function displayResults(response: any) {
        const formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
        // document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
        console.log(response)
      }
    })
  }
```

Home.module.ts
[image]

Comment: [gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference) is the embded api and that only supports Google analytics v3 not v4.   The response is different you cant mix them.

Comment: Okay I fixed that but still it won't load, do i need to put auth or something like that?

Comment: I suggest you follow the guide. yes you need to be authorized https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1

Comment: I can make that work but only with js, do you have some turtorial to make that to works with angular and ts?

Comment: The Embeded API is js.  Sorry i am not an angular or ts developer and we dont supply tutorials here.  We help you fix issues with your solution.   I recommend following the official tutorial if you need one.   You could also use the Google analytics api to get the data and then create your own graphs.

Comment: How can i use Google analytics api? I thing that would be the best solution

Comment: Hi @Darko did you find any solution for this issue ?